# How does Hibernate Search know when an ORM entity has been updated?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Suppose I have a search application that uses Hibernate Search and a core application that creates and updates entities via Hibernate Core.

How does the search application know when an entity has been updated?  Is there some type of event system or is it looking at the database?

Comment: Hibernate search binds on the post insert/update/delete events that hibernate session is creating on each case. To ensure consistency, its also wrapped in the transaction and haven't picked up any way to avoid that(except if you manually invoke the search engine). If you update the DB directly, then a manual re-index would be required and also comes to a conflict in keeping the things simple by having only one application which performs i/o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AntJavaDev wrote, Hibernate Search uses event listeners.

See https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/d2cc0775f5bd84c1482ea4744df3d78392809c63/mapper/orm/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/mapper/orm/event/impl/HibernateSearchEventListener.java#L110

Edit: also relevant, [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-automatic-concepts)